# Java read k lines of n integers

Tags: java

I have an input (the console input, not from file). First line contains 3 integers: a,b,c . Then the next a+c lines contain 2 integers delimited by whitespace. E.G:

```
3 2 4
91 94
92 97
97 99
92 94
93 97
95 96
90 100
```

I have to read the first 3 numbers, then (in this case) 3+4 lines of 2 integers. How Can I read the input correctly? I am sending the file to online compiler (Codeforces.com if it matters)

Here is my code(I try to read the file partially but it works not as intended):

```
//reads the first 3 numbers
    public static int[] readInit(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] integers = new int[3];
    for(int i = 0; i <=2; i++)
    {
        integers[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    return integers;
}

//reads the next 3 lines
public static int[] read(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] integers = new int[2];
    for(int i = 0; i <=1; i++)
    {
        integers[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    return integers;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] initData = readInit();
    nrOfRecipes = initData[0];
    minNrRecommended = initData[1];
    nrOfQuestions = initData[2];

    for (int i=0; i<nrOfRecipes; i++){
        int[] data = read();
        minDegrees = data[0];
        maxDegrees = data[1];
        ...
    }
    ...
```

but this code reads only the first 3 integers from the first line. How can I read the data correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Make sure this code is compilable. Where is, for example, `initData` defined?

Comment: I've posted only a part of my code to avoid long and not useful code

Comment: Hint, `b` is only `2` in your example sample... it might not be `2` when they test it.

Comment: I've tested for a particular case. I know it but anyway thanks

Comment: if it does not work for 2, it will not work for 2000

Comment: You have `nrOfRecipes` and `nrOfQuestions` but you're only reading `nrOfRecipes` lines after the first line.

Comment: @DanielBickler - Perhaps the ... after that `for` includes a loop over `nrOfQuestions`.

Comment: @AndyThomas that's why it's a comment and not an answer. I want to be helpful but there's not enough there to answer.

Comment: @Kate How do you insert this multiline text into the console, and what does the Scanner show you?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the instructions, first read `a`, `b` and `c`. Then construct a 2D array. Then fill it. Finally (since I don't know what you want to do with your `k` lines), you might just print it.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = sc.nextInt(), b = sc.nextInt(), c = sc.nextInt();
int[][] arr = new int[a + c][b];
for (int i = 0; i < (a + c); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Given your example input, I get

```
[[91, 94], [92, 97], [97, 99], [92, 94], [93, 97], [95, 96], [90, 100]]
```

Comment: the problem is if I use nextInt(), I will get only the first int from the first line and when assigning b = sc.nextInt(), It will be the first int from the 2nd line

Comment: @KateCebotari You are mistaken. I have tested this code **with your posted input**.

Comment: How does this differ from the OP's example, other than eliminating the procedural abstraction? What issue is she having with her current code?

Comment: @AndyThomas OP isn't reading all of the values, and what value do you see in the purported procedural abstraction?

Comment: In c++ for e.g If I paste all the example above all the data is read correctly. In java if I paste the example above, only the first line is being read from all the data as nextLine takes only the first line. I was wondering if it is possible to read all the input data at a time instead of introducing line by line

Comment: I don't see any need to defend procedural abstraction. The OP knows that she's using a constant rather than the value of `b`. Her sample code does not explicitly read `c` additional values, but she says that only the first line is being read - implying that the `a` rows following aren't being read at all. Why is this occurring? How does your answer differ in a way that fixes the problem cited? If it's because she keeps creating a new Scanner on System.in, that should be part of the answer.

Comment: @AndyThomas Creating a Scanner on `System.in` isn't a problem. Unless it's being done in a `try-with-resources` (or she's explicitly closing the `Scanner` somewhere else). Unfortunately, that is pure speculation. I'm answering how to read k lines of n integers...

Comment: @Kate Only the first line is read? Try to inspect your line endings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your issue correctly, but if you want to just read the two `integers` in each line depending on the 1st and 3rd `int` in the first line, you can use something like:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        String[] first = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        int lines = Integer.parseInt(first[0]) + Integer.parseInt(first[2]);
        while (lines-- > 0) {
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            // Do whatever you want here with the two integers
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
If input is through `System.in`, `nextLine` will keep reading each line at a time and wont read the first line only. However, you are reinitializing the `scanner` in every method. Try using one `scanner` for all of your methods.
You can do that by initializing the Scanner outside of your methods as the follownig:

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

then inside your methods use `sc.nextInt();` without declaring the `Scanner`.

Comment: In c++ for e.g If I paste all the example above all the data is read correctly. In java if I paste the example above, only the first line is being read from all the data as nextLine takes only the first line. I was wondering if it is possible to read all the input data at a time instead of introducing line by line

Comment: @KateCebotari I have updated the answer, please check it out

Comment: @KateCebotari I just realized you are trying to read all data at once instead of reading each `integer`/`line` at a time, please let me know if that is the case so I update my answer